# Center align a table vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

```css
.cls_forgotpwd_container
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 350px;
    /*margin: auto;*/
    width: 350px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.cls_forgotpwd_table label
{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.cls_forgotpwd_table input[type="password"]
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}

body
{
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="cls_forgotpwd_container">
    <form class="cls_forgotpwd_form" id="forgotpwd_form">
        <table class="cls_forgotpwd_table">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Password</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></input></td>
            </tr>
                <td><label>Confirm Password</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="confirm_password"></input></td>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="cls_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Change It"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Doubts**

1) I tried `display: table` and `tabel-cell with vertical-align:middle` But it is not working in my scenario. And this data is not tabular, so i don't think its a right way.

2) I don't prefer `position absolute` with `top and left values in %`. If i don't get other options, I will go with this one.

Is there any other possibilities to center align the div? Or Which one should i use in the above two options? If i have to choose option1, It's not working in my case.

I don't prefer `margin` to center align this. And `flex` is not supported by IE.

`margin:0 auto` with `width:350px` successfully center aligned the div.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: use margin-top:50% and margin-left:50%

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/dwr7mq70/

Comment: @Dmitriy You could add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code

`body, html` - default - `height: auto;` `width: auto;`

```css
.cls_forgotpwd_container
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 350px;
    /*margin: auto;*/
    width: 350px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.cls_forgotpwd_table label
{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.cls_forgotpwd_table input[type="password"]
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}

body
{
    display: table;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="cls_forgotpwd_container">
    <form class="cls_forgotpwd_form" id="forgotpwd_form">
        <table class="cls_forgotpwd_table">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Password</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></input></td>
            </tr>
                <td><label>Confirm Password</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="confirm_password"></input></td>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="cls_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Change It"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

so that would be centered necessary for `body` and `html` add - `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`

```css
html, 
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table;     
    border: 3px solid #f00;
}

.cls_forgotpwd_container {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 350px;      
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.cls_forgotpwd_container form{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.cls_forgotpwd_table label {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.cls_forgotpwd_table input[type="password"] {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="cls_forgotpwd_container">
    <form class="cls_forgotpwd_form" id="forgotpwd_form">
        <table class="cls_forgotpwd_table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Password</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="password"></input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="confirm_password"></input>
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="cls_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Change It"></input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: necessary for body and html add - height: 100% and width: 100%

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easily with CSS [`transform`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), browser support: **IE9+**

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qq65j39c/)**

```
.cls_forgotpwd_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

If you do need to support **IE8+** here it is, see the comments inline.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxmgjn4w/)**

```
html, body, .cls_forgotpwd_container {
    height: 100%; /*make all the contaniers to 100% height*/
}
body {
    margin: 0; /*reset default margin*/
}
.cls_forgotpwd_container {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto; /*horizontally center itself*/
}
.cls_forgotpwd_form {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; /*vertically center things inside*/
}
```

There is a small issue should be corrected - `<input>` is self-closing tag.

This is wrong `<input></input>`

This is correct `<input>` or `<input/>`

Comment: Thanks. And Your second method is working nice without border. If somebody tries to apply border, it would cover the entire height area which is not wanted by most of the people. Am i right?

Comment: Ooops, Silllly Mistake. I tried to apply the border for the form container.